# How does the MAV work in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

When using the MAV in *Battlefield 3*, I can spot enemies using the select key to mark them, but I dont get any points.  Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get 20 *additional* spot points if that enemy is killed after you spot them with the MAV (or T-UGS). And potentially a ribbon if that happens a few times in a row.

Also, you can left click to lock on and blow up enemy equipment, things like the recon mobile deployment beacon and other MAVs.

It's worth noting that the MAV *also* includes a passive detection ability exactly like the T-UGS -- if you leave it in a location sitting by itself, it will send out periodic "pings" that highlight any moving enemies nearby. If you don't want to be tied down piloting the MAV, it's a good strategy to drop the MAV in some out of the way area where it won't be spotted easily by enemies, and let it passively detect enemies even without you operating it. It is more effective when piloted, of course, but it also works with no human intervention too, kind of like SOFLAM.

Note that as of the latest patch, the MAV will destroy itself shortly after you respawn. It lives only as long as you do, including the time you are dead and waiting for respawn, it is not a permanent artifact once deployed.

Comment: It is worth noting that (unlike the behavior in Bad Company 2 and during the Beta) teammates will only see 3D pips for spotted enemies if they are in their line-of-sight. So if an enemy is behind a wall, your teammates must be paying attention to their mini-map to gain any benefit from your spotting.

Comment: Apart from spotting of course, the most useful thing about the MAV is destroying enemy EOD bots that are traveling for the MCOM Stations. Also it's really fun to run people over with the MAV :)

Comment: ALSO, AFAIK it is 30 points in total. First 10 points from the normal "Spot bonus" (which applies from all spotted-enemies-which-are-killed) an an *additional* +20 from the fact that you used the MAV to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to anger people.  Flying the MAV at full speed into the faces of enemies will kill them (considered a roadkill death, which you get full kill points for).  It doesn't injure the MAV but is pretty tricky to get the hang of.

Comment: If you're a fan of cheap, BS kills, you should do this. I personally root for people's systems to lock up and die when they abuse this "tactic".

Comment: @Yatrix, I guess someone has a grudge against MAVs. The problam imho that you are not moving or destorying the MAV with your gun. Maybe next time pay attention what's happeing around you.

Comment: This was patched in the last update and will now destroy the MAV when you get a roadkill (so you can now only get 1 kill per MAV)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this happen once after a guy killed me his entire squad was wiped out by a MAV ambush from behind. It was perhaps the most beautiful thing I've ever seen.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer